# how to delete the elements in html using simple html dom?

Tags: php, jquery, html, dom, simple-html-dom

I am trying this but its not working

```
 include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
             $handle = file_get_html('file name.php');
             if (!empty($handle)) {
             $ret = $handle->find('div', 0);//this is able to find the element
             echo $ret;
             $ret->outertext = '';//this is **NOT** deleting the video
```

`outertext='';` is not working i dont know why

i have tried `$handle->find('div[id="'.$i.'"]', 0)->outertext = '';`
but this also didn't work.

any other ways I haven't tried??

Comment: why is there a space here file name.php may be that is the problem

Comment: @IllegalArgument oh that I put for better understanding real name is `'exercise/Exercise.php'`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why this would make a difference, but try doing your modification inline with the find.

```
$handle->find('div', 0)->outertext = '';
```